# How to run rtorrent as systemd service under a dedicated user?

Tags: linux, systemd, daemon, rtorrent

I am trying to get `rtorrent` to run as a `systemd service`, but the service wouldn't start. Here's the config file and any log I can get. Ask for more info if you need to.
I am running:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

```
$ systemctl status rtorrent
● rtorrent.service - rTorrent
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rtorrent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-05-27 08:52:43 EEST; 5min ago
    Process: 20199 ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -P -s rt -n rtorrent /usr/bin/rtorrent (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 20205 ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux send-keys -t rt:rtorrent C-q (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 20201 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 27 08:52:43 $MACHINE systemd[1]: Starting rTorrent...
May 27 08:52:43 $MACHINE tmux[20199]: rt:
May 27 08:52:43 $MACHINE systemd[1]: Started rTorrent.
May 27 08:52:43 $MACHINE tmux[20205]: no server running on /tmp/tmux-110/default
May 27 08:52:43 $MACHINE systemd[1]: rtorrent.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 27 08:52:43 $MACHINE systemd[1]: rtorrent.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The config file..

```
[Unit]
Description=rTorrent
Requires=network.target local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=forking
KillMode=none
User=rt
Group=adm
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -P -s rt -n rtorrent /usr/bin/rtorrent
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux send-keys -t rt:rtorrent C-q
WorkingDirectory=/tmp/tmux-110/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Some more logs:

```
$ journalctl -u rtorrent
May 27 08:52:43 $MACHINE systemd[1]: Starting rTorrent...
May 27 08:52:43 $MACHINE tmux[20199]: rt:
May 27 08:52:43 $MACHINE systemd[1]: Started rTorrent.
May 27 08:52:43 $MACHINE tmux[20205]: no server running on /tmp/tmux-110/default
May 27 08:52:43 $MACHINE systemd[1]: rtorrent.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 27 08:52:43 $MACHINE systemd[1]: rtorrent.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

So far I have added the user `rt` to the `adm` group, but I can't figure it out why `tmux` can't be started as `rt`. I also authorized `rt` user to launch services thanks to the enable-linger option: `loginctl enable-linger rt`
I first added the `rt` user with:`sudo adduser --system  --gecos "rTorrent Client" --disabled-password --group --home /home/rt rt`.
How to make `rtorrent` run as `systemd` service with `tmux`as a dedicated user? Or is there any other way to run it as service with `systemd`? Any help is really appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
So, just to get a fresh start, I have created a new user named `rtorrent` with: `sudo adduser --system  --gecos "rTorrent System Client" --disabled-password --group --home /home/rtorrent rtorrent`  and changed the `/etc/systemd/system/rtorrent.service` file to this (also adding `system.daemon = true` in `/home/rtorrent/.rtorrent.rc`, [because of this post](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/pull/446)):

```
[Unit]
Description=rTorrent System Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=rtorrent
Group=rtorrent

ExecStartPre=-/bin/rm -f /home/rtorrent/.session/rtorrent.lock
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rtorrent -o import=/home/rtorrent/.rtorrent.rc
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But after all I get this error:

```
$ systemctl status rtorrent
● rtorrent.service - rTorrent System Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rtorrent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-05-27 10:12:26 EEST; 2s ago
    Process: 22855 ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /home/rtorrent/.session/rtorrent.lock (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 22856 ExecStart=/usr/bin/rtorrent -o import=/home/rtorrent/.rtorrent.rc (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
   Main PID: 22856 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
```

Why is this happening? What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE 2:**
One more thing, [This post](https://askubuntu.com/a/676022/1190489) suggest not dropping any files in the `/etc/systemd/system/`, but instead, to drop them in `/usr/local/lib/systemd/system` which in Debian based systems is in `/lib/systemd/system`. Therefore, I moved the `unit-file` there and when enabling it, it automatically created a `symlink` to `/etc/systemd/system/`. But still,, I get this error:

```
$ sudo systemctl status rtorrent
● rtorrent.service - rTorrent System Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rtorrent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-05-27 10:39:14 EEST; 924ms ago
    Process: 24530 ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /home/rtorrent/.session/rtorrent.lock (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 24531 ExecStart=/usr/bin/rtorrent -o import=/home/rtorrent/.rtorrent.rc (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
   Main PID: 24531 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
```

Comment: In OpenSuse, at least, the proper way to modify the system file involves using some variant of the following command. This leaves the original file in place rather than creating one in another system directory shadowing it:

`systemctl edit --full rtorrent.service`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### rtorrent as a daemon and screen / tmux

**Starting from rtorrent 0.9.7, screen / tmux [is not required anymore](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/wiki/Daemon_Mode)** to run rtorrent as a system-wide daemon **if you don't need its console interface**. It was previously mandatory since rtorrent required an active terminal to be controlled, even if you only used an external interface (e.g. ruTorrent) to manage your torrent via SCGI.

If you really want to run rtorrent using screen or tmux to be able to control it using a terminal, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802189/how-to-run-tmux-screen-with-systemd-230)

Just add the following configuration to your `rtorrent.rc` file to run rtorrent as a daemon:

```
system.daemon.set = true
```

You **will only be able to control it using an external software** via SCGI, so you must also configure SCGI in the config file:

```
# Bind SCGI to localhost only on port 5000
network.scgi.open_port = 127.0.0.1:5000
```

*Note*: your configuration file may already include a `scgi_port = ...` directive. It's the older way of opening the SCGI port and is equivalent to the above, but don't put both of them in your config file or rtorrent will complain about the port being already opened: `Error in option file: <file>:<line>: SCGI already enabled.`.

### Service file

The previous answer from Ljm Dullaart is correct about how the service file should look. But you must pay attention to the rtorrent config file in use.

By default, rtorrent will load the `~/.rtorrent.rc` file as its config file. If you also load it using the `-o import ~/.rtorrent.rc` option in your unit file, it will make rtorrent load the file **twice**. It results about rtorrent complaining about the SCGI port already opened since it reads the `network.scgi.open_port` or `scgi_port` config lines twice. You should also add the `-n`option switch to prevent rtorrent from reading its default config file

The unit file `/etc/systemd/system/rtorrent.service` should look like:

```
[Unit]
Description=rTorrent system daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=torrent
Group=torrent

# Change these settings to match your install:
Environment=RTORRENT_DIR=/home/torrent
Environment=RTORRENT_CONFIG=${RTORRENT_DIR}/.rtorrent.rc
Environment=SESSION_DIR=${RTORRENT_DIR}/session

ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f ${SESSION_DIR}/rtorrent.lock
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rtorrent -n -o import=${RTORRENT_CONFIG}

Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I will try it these days. You're probably right though.

Answer (score 5):

I do not understand why anyone would want a `tmux` around your `rtorrent`. What is the function of the `tmux` here? You could try https://askubuntu.com/questions/802189/how-to-run-tmux-screen-with-systemd-230
if you absolutely want that extra process overhead.

Anyways, create a `/etc/systemd/system/rtorrent.service` with

```
[Unit]
Description=rTorrent System Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=rtorrent
Group=rtorrent

ExecStartPre=-/bin/rm -f /home/rt/.session/rtorrent.lock
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rtorrent -o import=/home/rt/rtorrent.rc
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

That should answer your last question.

Comment: "I do not understand why anyone would want a tmux around your rtorrent. What is the function of the tmux here?" - I am still a newbie when it comes about `rtorrent`, but this is how all the tutorials put it, the very few that exist..

Comment: I'm sorry, but `tmux` is a bit of a frustration for me. Keep in mind that `tmux` is a terminal multiplexer, not a generalized wrapper around things. In start-up scripts (or systemd-files), you should never  need a `tmux`.

Comment: Thanks, I will remember that. Also, look on the update on the post.

Comment: in your `adduser`, you gave `/home/rt` as home directory for the user `rt`. In the unit-file you use `/home/rtorrent`

Comment: I have deleted the `rt` user. I am only working with the `rtorrent` user now.  So everything is on `rtorrent` user.

Comment: Could you try a `rtorrent /usr/bin/rtorrent -o import=/home/rtorrent/.rtorrent.rc` as the user `rtorrent` to verify that `rtorrent` works at all?

Comment: yeah, I did run it and it tried running `rtorrent` as my current user: 
`rtorrent: Could not lock session directory: "/home/robinhood/.rtorrent-session/", No such file or directory`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124746/discussion-between-robinhood-and-ljm-dullaart).

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped me:

1. Install default config as described [here](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/wiki/CONFIG-Template). That page contains script that downloads and update config to use current username.

   ```shell
   curl -Ls "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/rakshasa/rtorrent/CONFIG-Template.md" \
       | sed -ne "/^######/,/^### END/p" \
       | sed -re "s:/home/USERNAME:$HOME:" >~/.rtorrent.rc
   mkdir -p ~/rtorrent/
   ```
2. Uncomment these 3 lines in config :

   ```
   system.daemon.set = true
   network.scgi.open_local = (cat,(session.path),rpc.socket)
   execute.nothrow = chmod,770,(cat,(session.path),rpc.socket)
   ```
3. Start service as described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/651593/226980), but do not specify `-o` parameter.

   ```
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/rtorrent
   ```

   `rtorrent` picks up config from `~/.rtorrent.rc` automatically.

You will know if the config was loaded twice if you see lots of these errors in logs:

```
1687310792 C Caught exception: 'Error in option file: ~/.rtorrent.rc:11: Invalid key.'.
```